# ASP MVC Bootstrap - Select2 DropDownListFor Displays Duplicate Boxes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have an ASP.net MVC project.  All of my DropDownListFor's display as 2 boxes instead of 1.  This is what the view looks like currently:

[image]

This is what the view SHOULD look like:

[image]

Here is the code from the view:

```
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 ">
        <div class="form-group select-280">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HoleID)
            <br />
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HoleID, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["HoleList"], new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HoleID)
       </div>
   </div>
```

Javascript from the view to make the DropDownListFor Searchable (Select2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#HoleID").select2();

}
```

---

Why are all of my DropDownListFor's displaying as duplicates, and how can I correct this bug?

**EDIT**

Removing the `.select2()` fixes the bug and removes the duplicate dropdown... however that makes the remaining dropdown not searchable.  how can I fix this while still maintaining the search functionality?

Comment: Try to remove LabelFor

Comment: @ishanjoshi that did not work.  Other suggestions?

Comment: why you need to put  $("#HoleID").select2(); apply as class for select2  in razor

Comment: @ishanjoshi can you please show how?  do you inside of the class = "form-control"?

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HoleID, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["HoleList"], new { @class = "form-control select2" })

Comment: @ishanjoshi applying select2 as a class in razor does not implement the select2 search functionality and the dropdown is treated as a regular select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was determined to be a server error via the Visual Studio publish process.  The bootstrap select2 files were not existing correctly in the server.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this using Kendo, and it's all around the form-control.  The issue is the dropdown gets transformed into something more dynamic; the original SELECT element might actually get hidden in the UI.  Select2 is probably using multiple elements to represent the select, and the original form-control class gets applied to both elements, and forces them to show, instead of show and hide.  Or the form-control class is forcing the original select to show.

I had to stop using form-control, and then create a special class just for kendo controls just to not cause one of the elements to always show...

The way to figure that all out is inspect the markup.  You'll see the form-control class getting passed down to the internal elements.

Comment: Removing form-control does not remove the second box.  Upon inspecting the markup, I can see that the top box is a "Select" and the bottom box is a "Span"

Comment: From my experience (though I haven't used select2), normally what happens is the SELECT element gets hidden (you really can't style it) but keeps it in the DOM so that when a postback happens, the selected value is presered.  Then, it creates another element to display the stylish dropdown.  If both are displaying, something is going wrong most likely........